# Is there a rule to adjust minimum RAM for Postgres based on amount of data?

Tags: postgresql

I'm curious how RAM is adjusted for the Postgres db based on storage. For example, is there such settings like "db needs at least X amount of RAM for Y amount of data"?

#### Example

How much RAM would people use for 500GB of data? And what's the role of index in this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such rule. The important criteria for determining RAM usage are:

- How big is the *resident set*, that is, the part of the database that is actually used by the workload?
- How many concurrent client connections do you want to support?
- What kind of SQL statements do you have? Small ones (OLTP) or ones that join or aggregate large tables?

That said, the answer is usually that the more RAM you can get, the better. The more data are cached, the less I/O you will have.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will partitioning help? If I partition the data, could I be okay with less RAM? And will 2GB RAM be enough for 500GB data?

Comment: Partitioning typically does not help with that, and as I said, I cannot tell if 2GB RAM will be enough for 500GB database. But I suspect it might be too little. "The more, the better."

Comment: @stackyname: 2GB is the minimum required main memory to run Postgres. It will run, but will severely be limited by I/O throughput

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you. What's the benefit of partitioning then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. Do you have any experience with such large data and RAM recommendations?

Comment: @stackyname I do (10s of billions of rows in a single table with multi-terabyte big databases). Everything Laurenz said and keeps saying is what you need to know. You can have a database that's 100 TB big and only need 4 GB of RAM because the workload only actively uses 4 GB (or less) of data at a time. Conversely a 10 GB database could require 100 GB of RAM if the workload requires it (does a lot of ad-hoc stuff with temp tables etc). No one can tell you how much RAM you'll need without knowing the workload. Like Laurenz said, the only rule of thumb is the more the better.

Comment: @J.D. That's very insightful, thank you so much!
Is there way to know how much RAM is being used in certain workloads? What kind of queries consumes how much RAM etc.

Comment: @stackyname Yes but that should be a separate Post you ask on here regarding performance analysis / tuning. I'm not an expert on PostgreSQL specifically (but what I said above holds true in most modern database systems), so asking this question in a new Post will be your best bet. There are ways to tell how much Memory your server's running queries are currently consuming.

Comment: @J.D. You're right. I'll do that. Thank you so much!